# How to view webpage on my server from another computer?

Tags: networking, web-applications, webserver, ip-address

I have a web application I have developed on a server on my home computer. Is it possible to access that web page from another computer on my home network?

My naive approach was just enter my ip address followed by the port number `:8888` which the server is listening on...

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: SU Q/A's that may be helpful http://superuser.com/questions/432794/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-my-wamp-server and http://superuser.com/questions/422596/connecting-to-localhost-with-smartphone-possible/422599#422599

Comment: @Sampo Thanks they are helpful.

Comment: @Sampo, you should now put that in a Answer. Upvote pending.

Comment: @arttronics I'll appreciate that but I'm not willing to write new answer here just now (_with mobile phone's keyboard..._), if my SU answers was useful then feel free upvote on them. Actually this question may be more on superuser's scope. If still needed I will come back with more precise answer after few days, this is all I can do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was easier to set up remote access to the server by setting up port-forwarding on my router and using [no-ip](http://www.no-ip.com/) for DNS management. They have a decent walkthrough to get it all up and running. So i simply have to type in `my-address.no-ip.org` to access my site from any remote device.

Otherwise the links to questions on superuser that Sampo posted are worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help but you can use an ssh connection to your computer. But you need to do it from a shell (from terminal on a mac, use putty on a PC)